# I have 2 subclasses that I need to put into one Observable list

Tags: javafx

I have 2 sublclasses that are extended from the same parent class. I need to either:

1. put both of these subclasses into an ObservableList 

**OR** 

2.create two separate ObservableList and then combine them into one. 

Is there a way to do either one of these things? I'm new to Java programming so If I didn't explain enough please let me know.

fyi: I will be adding and deleting data from this list via tableview.

Comment: So... what happens if you try the first option?

Comment: Couldn't you do this?  ObservableList<? extends ParentClass> listOfParents = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Comment: @purringpigeon Just `ObservableList<ParentClass> listOfParents = ...;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever heard of polymorphism? Just initialize the list with the parent class type. Since both the sub class objects are of type of the parent class, both can be stored.

Comment: For the first sentence: I guess, based on the nick of the OP, that he's new to programming :)

Comment: Yes I agree.. never meant to be rude there, after all even myself knows only a little. :)